# How can I make multiple pivot tables mimic the filters (report and row label) of another on just that sheet in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

So I have multiple pivot tables on a single sheet in excel. I have a long list of months in the row labels. The report filter is filterable by names. All of the columns in the pivots are just sums of data.

What I'm looking for (and I'm guessing a macro is the only way to do it), is a way to be able to change the filters of one of the pivots on that sheet and it update the other pivots on only that sheet to mimic the filters (both report and row label) of the one that I changed. Nothing else should change in the other pivot tables - just the filters.

Unfortunately, I literally know nothing about coding vba (I know a bit of java and stuff but I've never done any macro coding). I was able to copy a macro from the internet that did part of what I need; it updates the report filter but doesn't update the dates in the row label filter. Here's the coding for that:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
On Error Resume Next
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ptMain As PivotTable
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pfMain As PivotField
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim bMI As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Set wsMain = ActiveSheet
Set ptMain = Target

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'change all fields for all pivot tables on active sheet

For Each pfMain In ptMain.PageFields
    bMI = pfMain.EnableMultiplePageItems
        For Each pt In wsMain.PivotTables
            If pt <> ptMain Then
                pt.ManualUpdate = True
                Set pf = pt.PivotFields(pfMain.Name)
                        bMI = pfMain.EnableMultiplePageItems
                        With pf
                            .ClearAllFilters
                            Select Case bMI
                                Case False
                                    .CurrentPage = pfMain.CurrentPage.Value
                                Case True
                                    .CurrentPage = "(All)"
                                    For Each pi In pfMain.PivotItems
                                        .PivotItems(pi.Name).Visible = pi.Visible
                                    Next pi
                                    .EnableMultiplePageItems = bMI
                            End Select
                        End With
                        bMI = False

                Set pf = Nothing
                pt.ManualUpdate = False
            End If
        Next pt
Next pfMain

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is there anyway to do what I'm looking to do? Your help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Ok 1st things first :) Avoid using `On Error Resume Next`. It's like telling the the Application to SHUT UP when it finds an error :) Now can I see a workbook sample so that I can get my references correct?

Comment: Hey sorry it's taken me so long to get back. Got put on another project for the day and I'm just now getting back to this. Unfortunately the data inside the document is sensitive, so I can't send you the one that I'm actually using, but I could probably make a new one with different data. Would that work?

Comment: Yes that would work. I am sure you can then modify the code that I give you to apply it to the real time scenario?

Comment: How should I get the file to you?

Comment: You may upload the file at www.wikisend.com and share the link here.

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/833854/SampleWorkbookPivotAutoMimic.xlsm thanks for your help by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your pivottables it seems that all you need to do to the above code is repeat the steps from setting the pivotfield value to reflect the date.  This is done by 
adding a variant of the loop set up by the line:

```
    set pf = pt.pivotfields(pfmain.name)
```

to

```
    set pf = pt.pivotfields(pfmain.nameofyourrowfiltervariable)
```

the full code is below, i would also avoid on error resume next

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ptMain As PivotTable
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pfMain As PivotField
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim bMI As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsMain = ActiveSheet
    Set ptMain = Target

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'change all fields for all pivot tables on active sheet

    For Each pfMain In ptMain.PageFields
        bMI = pfMain.enablemultiplepageitems
        For Each pt In wsMain.PivotTables
          If pt <> ptMain Then
            pt.ManualUpdate = True
            Set pf = pt.PivotFields(pfMain.Name)
                    bMI = pfMain.EnableMultiplePageItems
                    With pf
                        .ClearAllFilters
                        Select Case bMI
                            Case False
                                .CurrentPage = pfMain.CurrentPage.Value
                            Case True
                                .CurrentPage = "(All)"
                                For Each pi In pfMain.PivotItems
                                    .PivotItems(pi.Name).Visible = pi.Visible
                                Next pi
                                .EnableMultiplePageItems = bMI
                        End Select
                    End With
                    bMI = False

               Set pf = pt.pivotfields(pfMain.nameofdatevariable)
               dates = pfMain.enablemultiplepageitems
               with pf
                   .clearallfilters
                   select case dates
                       case false
                               .currentpage = pfmain.currentpage.value
                       case true
                               .currentpage = "(All)"
                               for each pi in pfmain.pivotitems
                                    .pivotitems(pi.nameofdatevariable).visible = pi.visible
                                next pi
                                .enablemultiplepageitems = dates
                       end select
               end with
               date = false
               set pf = nothing
               pt.ManualUpdate = False
           End If
       Next pt
   Next pfMain

  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

try it and see if it works I have not tested this

Comment: Hey sorry it's taken me so long to get back. Got put on another project for the day and I'm just now getting back to this. I tried replacing your code with mine and it came back with a "variable not defined" error on the dates variable. Do you have to set variables up prior to using them like in java?

Comment: @Scott: Ouch! `On Error Resume Next`? and that too twice! Double OUCH!

Comment: @dootcher: You are getting that error because `dates` is not defined and on top of the code you have `Option Explicit` which will force you to declare your variables. I have not seen the complete code that scott has given but from the looks of `Select Case`, declare `dates` as boolean. `Dim dates as Boolean`

Comment: Well, I'm now not getting any error any more. But now, the "mimic" is completely broken on both filters. Not only do the other pivots not mimic the first anymore (for either filter), but also, no matter what I do with the date filter it automatically switches the main report filter to All. I'm semi starting to understand the coding (its actually somewhat more like Java than I originally thought), but I'm still lost fixing this problem :(