# How to apply One pivot table filter to other Pivot table Automatically

Tags: vba, filter, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have 3 Pivot tables in a worksheet "Sheet3" and with names Pivot1, Pivot2, Pivot3 respectively. All the three pivot tables have same fields but only difference is the structure.

I'm trying to apply one filter which is applied in Pivot1 to Pivot2, Pivot3 without calling a macro manually. Which means, once I applied the "Date" filter in Pivot1 I want the same filter to be applied for Pivot2, Pivot3.

Is it possible to apply filters to one pivot table through a macro which will be triggered automatically when one filter is changed in a pivot table? Any help is appreciated. A sample macro will be great for me. I tried the solution for the same problem given here: [How can I make multiple pivot tables mimic the filters (report and row label) of another on just that sheet in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763659/how-can-i-make-multiple-pivot-tables-mimic-the-filters-report-and-row-label-of) but I neither understood the code nor the code is updating the pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2010 or later, just insert a Slicer for the field of interest, and then connect that Slicer to the other PivotTables by right-clicking on it, selecting 'Report Connections' from the right-click menu, then selecting the checkboxes of the other PivotTables you want to control. This assumes all PivotTables are based on the same data source.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that I'm using Excel 2007

Comment: Okay. How many fields are in this PivotTable, and roughly how many PivotItems in each field? Reason I ask is that if the Pivots are small, you can use fairly simple code to sync them. But if they are large, syncing can take minutes unless you use a more intelligent - but vastly more complex - approach.

Comment: Hi, My pivot table is huge. not just large. But I found another solution. I have coded a macro to filter all tables at a time. instead of mimicing one from another